# How to access Vue Instance from mixins?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I would like to implement this kind of logic that assign `this.$store.value` to local data.
This is how I do in pages/index.vue for instance.

```
method: {
  this.value = this.$store.value
}
```

I want to write it down into mixins because I actually have another logics around it and I use some pages.

However, I don't know how should I access `this`(VueInstnce) from mixins?

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported by Vue because mixin runs first before component's code,
then mixin is bound (merged) by Vue to the component instance so it's easy to access mixin from component/instance scope, but not vice versa.

To achieve your need I think the mixin method (like `created`) should be run (for example) with a given reference to the instance of your component as a parameter, but it's not like that.

However, if you reorganize your code to run what you need from `instance`.`created`
accessing there methods and data of mixin is possible and passing arguments on your own:

```js
var mixin = {
    data: {mixin: 'mixin'},
    created: function () {
    console.log('mixin hook called')
    },
    methods: { test: function(arg){console.log(arg); } }
};

vm=new Vue({
    data: {component: 'component'},
    mixins: [mixin],
    created: function () {
    console.log('called hook of ' + this.component + ' and accessing ' + this.mixin)
    },
});

vm.test(vm.mixin);
vm.test(vm.component);  // no problem to run mixin's method with component's data
```

```
> mixin hook called
> called hook of component and accessing mixin
> mixin
> component
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I don't know if it's considered a bad practice but I have managed to accomplish one-way data transmission **without** an `event bus`.

I am using `vuejs 3` with `composition api`. **Requirement**: all components shall be able to access a global singleton component shown on top of whole app.

`plugin.js` - here we use the `created` event in `mixin` to get a reference of an component instance. In **example** below I always have just 1 `tracker` component instance (global popup). **If you have a different more complex scenario I would recommend sticking with event bus solution instead..**

```
import Tracker from "@/plugins/ProgressTracker/components/Tracker.vue";

export default {
  install(app, params = {}) {
    app.component("tracker", Tracker);

    let instance = undefined;

    app.mixin({
      created() {
        if (this.$options.name === "ProgressTrackerPopup") {
          instance = this;
        }
      },
    });

    const progressTracker = () => {
      //
    };

    progressTracker.show = function () {
      instance.show();
    };

    app.config.globalProperties.$progressTracker = progressTracker;
  },
};
```

`useProgressTracker.js` - globally reusable composable function that exposes `show` method

```
import { ref, computed, getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

export default function useProgressTracker() {
  const internalInstance = getCurrentInstance();
  const progressTracker = internalInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties.$progressTracker;

  const show = () => {
    progressTracker.show();
  };

  return {
    show,
  };
}
```

`Tracker.vue` - component that we need to globally access from any other component (methods of it).. **`name` is important.** It shall be set in order for the `mixin` to be able to detect your component creation

```
<template>
  <div class="onTop" v-if="isShow">test</div>
</template>
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "ProgressTrackerPopup",
  setup() {
    var isShow = ref(false);

    const show = () => {
      isShow.value = true;
    };

    return {
      isShow,
      show,
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.onTop{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0000004f;
}
</style>
```

this is it. Don't forget to register the plugin:

```
import ProgressTracker from "@/plugins/plugin.js";
// ..
app.use(ProgressTracker, {});
```

Now when you want the pop-up to be shown you invoke:

```
// <tracker />

import useProgressTracker from "@/plugins/ProgressTracker/use/useProgressTracker.js";

const tracker = useProgressTracker();
tracker.show();
```

The last line of code will basically invoke the `show` method on global component instance itself! Whereas if you used an `event bus` instead - you would have subscribed to the pop event on target component itself.

I find this solution to be useful when you don't want to deal with an event bus and the case is relatively trivial (you only have 1 global instance at all times). Though, you could of course use an array of instances and loop-invoke the methods on them in sequence.. :)